# Movie Identification - 2000-Current Werewolf

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, werewolf

I am trying to identify a werewolf movie that I remember watching.  I have exhausted my Google-Fu in this search.

I recall it being centered around two guys in their late teens or early to mid twenties.  There were visiting a house on a farm outside the city.  One of the two is attacked by a werewolf.  Typical waking up bloodied and no memory of how he got where he was.  At one point he's kidnapped by some thugs (don't remember why) and taken to a basement.  They were going to beat him up for something (perhaps information or money) and he ended up becoming a werewolf and freeing himself (and killing his captors).
Later in the movie he tries to protect his friend (and prove his claim) by getting in a metal cage/crate (in a barn or garage) but they don't make it in time and he attacks his friend.

That is the best I can recall.  I'd appreciate any assistance you all could provide in helping me track down this movie.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like the opening scenes of "[An American Werewolf In London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_American_Werewolf_in_London)"

***EDIT***

Parts of it also sound like the sequel "[An American Werewolf in Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_American_Werewolf_in_Paris)" which includes a basement scene.

***End Edit***

The protagonist (David) and his initial companion are these guys…

[image: David and Jack]

It's had a few poster forms… like this:

[image]

In the movie David regularly wakes up naked, in weird locations after a transformation to his werewolf state, not sure of what happened to himself.
[image: David wakes up with he wolves]

He also has visitations from a dead Jack…

[image: Dead Jack visits]

At the time the onscreen transformations were considered to be amongst the best…

[image: David transforms]

Comment: Except I don't recall the werewolf in AAWIL being kidnapped by thugs, and he couldn't protect his friend, because that friend was already dead.

Comment: He wasn't kidnapped true… but they do match the "late teens or early to mid twenties" and David does try to protect the "girlfriend interest" Nurse Price… it's a stretch I agree… but possibly the sequel and the orginal have been conflated here by the OP

Comment: Neither were the movies I am talking about, sadly.  I know both of those quite well.  Thanks for the suggestion @Craig

Answer (score 1):

This might be "Uncaged" (UK title "Beast Within") (2016).

The main character and his two friends are staying at an isolated cabin in the woods. He isn't attacked by a werewolf (deviating from your memory) but he does wake up naked and covered in blood. He decides to strap a Go Pro camera on his head, using that to discover he's turning into a werewolf.

He's inherited a big iron cage which he locks himself up in, trying to keep everyone else safe. His one friend doesn't believe him, thinking he's a normal serial killer, and gets attacked and scratched in the leg, which turns him into a werewolf as well.

The main character makes friends with a drug dealer's wife. The dealer's thugs kidnap him, and he transforms into a werewolf while they're torturing him which results in a bloodbath.

[image: werewolf]